# Как происходит работа с соотношением сторон экрана?

Tags: opengl, графика

Не могли бы вы мне слегка объяснить как происходит работа с соотношением сторон экрана? Ведь там все в процентном соотношении! Если посмотреть на фото, то видно что в режиме 16:9 горизонтальный отрезок получается длиннее вертикального при проецировании на плоскость экрана. Как тогда рисовать квадраты? Матрица переделывается или как?  [image: Как тут нарисовать квадрат?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это корректируется матрицей проекции. Например, в GLM функция [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) вторым параметром принимает соотношение сторон экрана (*aspect ratio*):

```
GLM_FUNC_DECL mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> glm::perspective(T fovy, T aspect, T near, T far);
```